# Linking with gcc, g++ and gfortran

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, fortran, gfortran

I have an static library `matrixlib.a` which I use to compile some `C` code. This code is compiled with `gcc` and it works fine. However I would like to introduce this library into a `C++` code and then it's when the problems start.
The way I am compiling the `C` code:

> gcc -I/matrix/include -O -Wall  example.c -c -o example.o
>   gfortran example.o /matrix/lib/matrixlib.a -lblas -fopenmp -o example_c

If now we swap `gcc` for `g++`:

> example.c:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `mygemm_solver(int,
>   double const*, double*, double*, int, int)'

being `mygemm_solver` the function that I am using `example.c` file. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to compile c as c, and C++ as C++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions in `example.c` are probably not declared `extern "C"`, so the C++ compiler is applying name-mangling to the generated symbol name.  The Fortran code likely doesn't use the mangled name, so when the linker goes to try to locate it the symbol can't be found.

The first step is to put prototypes of all of the functions you want to "export" from the C/C++ code into a header file.  Put this at the top:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

And then this at the bottom:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This has the effect of automatically applying `extern "C"` to all functions declared in the header, but only when you are compiling as C++.

However, it's important to note that C and C++ are different languages with differing semantics (for example, in regards to implicitly converting from `void *`).  You should compile C code with a C compiler, and C++ code with a C++ compiler.  It is technically possible to write code that is both valid C and C++, and that has the same semantics in both languages, but there is rarely a reason to do this.

Comment: @_cdhowie You are right, it's not declaring the `extern "C"`. If I edit the header would that work?

Comment: @Manolete If this header is included in `example.c` then it probably will.  The C++ compiler needs to see this so that the symbols it produces are not mangled.